# Jest: TypeError: jquery.extend is not a function

Tags: jquery, node.js, jestjs, babel-jest

Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: jquery.extend is not a function
```

Here I am trying to import a module and call a function in Jest test cases. When the test run initiates, the import module in test file is invoked and jquery.extend code inside the module throws the above exception.
I have added jsdom and jest-environment-dom packages to Yarn.

Comment: Check which branch of jQuery you're using. `$.extend()` is not included in jQuery.slim.js, only the full version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: version 3.6.1 is used